# Are reading commendations on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should questions about reading commendations / which books to read on what topic be allowed/encouraged on literature.se?

Comment: This site is fast, gosh. Why does this not popup, when I write my title / search for the term 'commendation'??

Comment: Maybe because the other question only talks about "recommendations", not "commendations".

Comment: Yes, but I think a good search query should handle such, dont u think?

Comment: Maybe, but the nice thing about duplicates is that they offer different wordings. The next person to search for "commendations" will find this post, and then the one it links to.

Comment: So I wont delete my otherwise use-free question...

Comment: You can delete it if you want to, but I wouldn't. There's no need to delete duplicates, unless the wording is nearly identical. This post could help people find the answer in the future.

Comment: I agree, thats what I was trying to say. I see, how it came across '*cocky*'.